# does Object.create also create own properties

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I know you can set the prototype of a new object with this function ([read mozzilla docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create))
but does it also create own properties if it's used within an object literal like this

```
return Object.create(this);
```

I also know this method from a Klass literal wich only copies the instance methods

```
var subclass = function() { };
subclass.prototype = parent.prototype;
klass.prototype = new subclass;
```

mostly I am interested in the object.create method

EDIT

```
  var Klass = {
  init: function(){},

  prototype: {
    init: function(){}
  },

  create: function(){
    var object = Object.create(this);
    console.log('object with class create');
    console.log(object);
    console.log("object's parent is this");
    console.log(this);
    object.parent = this;
    object.init.apply(object, arguments);
    console.log('returned object from create');
    console.log(object);
    return object;
  },

  inst: function(){
    var instance = Object.create(this.prototype);
    console.log('de instance na object create');
    console.log(instance);
    instance.parent = this;
    instance.init.apply(instance, arguments);
    console.log('arguments in inst');
    console.log(arguments);
    return instance;
  },

  proxy: function(func){
    var thisObject = this;
    return(function(){ 
      return func.apply(thisObject, arguments); 
    });
  },

  include: function(obj){
    var included = obj.included || obj.setup;
    for(var i in obj)
      this.fn[i] = obj[i];
    if (included) included(this);
  },

  extend: function(obj){
    var extended = obj.extended || obj.setup;
    for(var i in obj)
      this[i] = obj[i];
    if (extended) extended(this);
  }
};

Klass.fn = Klass.prototype;
Klass.fn.proxy = Klass.proxy;
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: "*copies the instance methods*" - what?

Comment: So `create` is supposed to create a subclass, and `inst` is supposed to create instances of that class? Why do classes need an `init` method? What is your question, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

[MDN Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

> Summary
>
> Creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

So lets take a look at an simple example with an Object instantiated with the `new` keyword and one with `Object.create`;

```
function objectDotCreate() {
    this.property = "is defined";
    this.createMe = function () {
        return Object.create(this);
    };
}
var myTestObject = new objectDotCreate();
console.log(myTestObject, myTestObject.createMe());
```

*[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ipipat/1/edit)*

Now taking a look at the console output

[image: Console Output]

*Left: `new` Right: `Object.create`*

As you can see both create a new Instance of an Object, with their properties.

Only `Object.create`

> Creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

And `new` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new))

> [...] creates an instance of a user-defined object type or of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

So the Instance, created using `Object.create`, gains access to the properties,because they are shadowed by its `prototype` and the one where `new` was used, has its own properties, defined by its constructor.

So no it doesn't create its own Properties. (Though you can pass an Object to directly define the Objects property descriptors)

Comment: ok, I have to think about this, as I am making prototype inheritance. I have a model with class properties and when I subclass it, with object.create(this), it will execute an init function wich is a class function..I ammended my question..

Comment: there are two init functions and it executes the class init

Comment: then in your example firebug output, the right site get's al of the objects properties and puts it in the prototype, then the object should not have own properties, but in firebug I can stil see the class properties/methods pointing to different versions of the init function..and then it executes the init function in class context..this is confusing because object.create(this) should be a new object without own/class properties/methods..

Answer (score 1):

> does it also create own properties

If you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), it says *No* - unless you tell it to do so with a second argument. It's basic use is to create a *new, empty* object with its internal prototype set to the argument. The second argument would work like [`defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) then.

> if it's used within an object literal like this
>
> `return Object.create(this);`

I don't see any object literal here, but as you don't use the second parameter the returned object will have no own properties.

Comment: thanks, this can get confusing unless I paste the whole class